# I'm struggling to get multiple modals, opened from different buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

! Updated code !
I'm recently trying to learn html/css to code a website. I've been following multiple tutorials but for some reason, my modals aren't working. The buttons to open/close modals aren't working. If anyone could offer any help it would be much appreciated!

Below I've included my html file, stylesheet, and javascript file.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/935b67cf83.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script src="JS.js"></script> <!-- used to link to javascript-->


    <title>yo</title>
</head>


<body>



    <section class="flex" id="portfolio">

        <h1>
            PROJECTS
            <!--- <div class="horizontalLine" </div> --->
        </h1>



        <div class="gallery">

            <div class="projectBox">
                <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />
                <div class="span">
                    <p1>MerseyTrainsLive</p1>
                    <p2>Android/Java</p2>

                    <button class="modal-open" data-target="#trainModal">Open Modal 1</button>
                    <!--- <a class="btn" id="TrainBtn" href="#">LEARN MORE</a>
                        --->

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="projectBox">
                <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />
                <div class="span">
                    <p1>MerseyTrainsLive</p1>
                    <p2>Android/Java</p2>

                    <button class="modal-open" data-target="#project2Modal">Open Modal 2</button>

                    <!---
                    <a class="btn" id="Project2Btn" href="#">LEARN MORE</a> --->
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="projectBox">
                <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />
                <div class="span">
                    <p1>MerseyTrainsLive</p1>
                    <p2>Android/Java</p2>

                    <button class="modal-open" data-target="#project3Modal">Open Modal 3</button>



                </div>

            </div>



        </div>



    </section>


    <!--pop-ups, bg-modal means background-->
    <div class="modal" id="trainModal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />

                <button class="modal-close" data-target="#trainModal">
                    &times;
                </button>

                <h2> MerseyTrainsLive</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p> idem espum </p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="modal" id="project2Modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />

                <button class="modal-close" data-target="#project2Modal">
                    &times;
                </button>

                <h2> project 2</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p> idem espum 2 </p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal" id="project3Modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <img src="images/merseyTrains.png" />

                <button class="modal-close" data-target="#project3Modal">
                    &times;
                </button>

                <h2> project 3</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p> idem espum 3 </p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


    <div id="overlay"> </div>



</body>


</html>
```

style.css

```
body {
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px; 
    text-align: center;

}

.horizontalLine {
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto

}


.gallery {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center; /*makes individual boxes centered*/
}
.gallery img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px; 
}

.gallery .projectBox {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    /*margin: 10px; /*can be used to make the photos spaced out*/
}


.gallery .projectBox img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 4px solid black;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    opacity: 1; 
}

/*when hover over image, the image disappears*/
.gallery .projectBox:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
}

.gallery .projectBox .span {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;

}

.gallery .projectBox .span p1 {
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.gallery .projectBox .span p2 {
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.gallery .projectBox:hover .span {
    opacity: 1; 
    display: block;

}


.gallery .projectBox .span a {
    
    text-decoration: none;
}


/*modal open buttons*/
.gallery .projectBox .span .modal-open {
    display: flex; /*makes layout nice :) */
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px; /*how far the lines of button are from text*/
    margin: 30px auto;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #f44336;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery .projectBox .span .modal-open:hover {
    color: white;
    background: #f44336;
}





/* popups */
.modal {

    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    z-index: 2; /*so appears on top of overlay*/
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
}

/*modal close close button*/
.modal-close {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.modal.active {
    
    display: flex; 
    
}

.modal .modal-content {
    display: flex; 
    border-radius: 4px; 
    position: relative; /*lets the .close position itself according to content*/
}

/*image for top of modal*/
.modal .modal-content img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.modal .modal-header .modal-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 14px;
    font-size: 42px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.overlay.active {
    display: block;
}
```

JS.js

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-open");
const close_btns = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-close");
const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

btns.forEach((btn) => {
    const target = btn.dataset.target;
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.querySelector(target).classList.add("active");
        overlay.classList.add("active");
    })
})

close_btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.querySelector(btn.dataset.target).classList.remove("active");
        overlay.classList.remove("active");
    })
})

window.onclick = (e) => {
    if (e.target == overlay) {
        const modals = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
        modals.forEach((modal) => modal.classList.remove("active"));
        overlay.classList.remove("active");
    }
}
```

Below is a screenshot of the website page

[image]

When I hover over the projectBoxes it reveals info on the project, and the button to open more info on the project (displayed in a modal)

[image]

Comment: Hi, what is `btns` in your JavaScript? I don't see it declared.

Comment: Got it, let me add a working solution in the answer box.

Comment: Hi, sorry I've edited my code to correct it for the `btn`(s) not being declared by renaming the buttons in the html document. Also, `btns` is declared at the top of the JS doc

Answer (score 0):

First, let's correct the HTML button to trigger modal number 3.

```
<button class="modal-open" data-target="#project3Modal">Open Modal 3</button>
```

Notice the change in "data-target" attribute. The value of this attribute should point to the "id" attribute of the respective modal (as per the JS implementation).

Next, for selecting the `overlay <div>`, let's use `document.getElementById` method. As there is only one `id="overlay"` in your HTML, selecting the element with its unique ID is a good practice, in my personal opinion.

So let's change the code in JS as below:

```
const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  const target = btn.dataset.target; // Declaring target 
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(target).classList.add("active");
    overlay.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

With the above two changes, everything should work well. If not, please let me know so I can assist you further. If you need clarity for above code, please do let me know. :)

Comment: Hi Nitin, I've changed the value for the target-target on button 3, it was an oversight of mine as I was just trying to get buttons 1 and 2 working and hadn't sorted button 3 properly yet. I'm still getting issues with the none of the buttons opening any modals.

Comment: Hmm. Here's a codepen link that you can refer. Also, I have added the `click` event handler for `btns` code in the answer.
https://codepen.io/Nitin-Chandran-Nair/pen/RwVmBbW?editors=1010

Comment: Have you tried with the `overlay` line change?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's an IDE issue or something as I just can't get the buttons to work. I'll update the code in the posted question now.  I changed the overlay line also

Comment: Hi Niten, I copy-pasted my code into codepen.io and it works fine in that. I think it must be an issue with visual studio? https://codepen.io/StuartGroom/pen/MWmdqwN

Comment: I checked your codepen link, everything looks good. Here are few other things to check - Do you see any errors in your IDE?
Are you running it on localhost? 
Is JavaScript enabled on browser?

Comment: Hi Nitin, I've tried it in a different IDE and still have the same issue as before. I do have javascript enabled in the browser and tbh I'm not sure whether I'm running on a local host. There are no errors  on either IDE

Comment: If you are using the exact same code that you had posted in your codepen, then it's weird that for some reason it is not working on your system. You can be sure that your code is correct, I do not see any errors there.